# How to get the domain name of my site within a Django template?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

How do I get the domain name of my current site from within a Django template? I've tried looking in the tag and filters but nothing there.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I think what you want is to have access to the request context, see RequestContext.

Comment: if you mean request.url, you only get the path minus the domain

Comment: `request.META['HTTP_HOST']` gives you the domain. In a template it would be `{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}`.

Comment: Be careful with using request metadata. It's coming from a browser and can be spoofed. In general, you'll probably want to go with what's suggested below by @CarlMeyer.

Comment: For my purposes, this has no security hole.

Comment: I guess, since Django 1.5 with the allowed hosts setting it's safe to use. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: Can someone elaborate on what the "security hole" is? If the user spoofs the `Host:` header and gets a response back with the spoofed domain somewhere on a page, how does that create a security hole? I don't see how that differs from a user taking the generated HTML and modifying himself before feeding it to his own browser.

Comment: It doesn't work when using nginx. It will return 127.0.0.1:8000. Anyone have solution for this?

Answer (score 137):

If you want the actual HTTP Host header, see Daniel Roseman's comment on @Phsiao's answer. The other alternative is if you're using the [contrib.sites framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#ref-contrib-sites), you can set a canonical domain name for a Site in the database (mapping the request domain to a settings file with the proper SITE_ID is something you have to do yourself via your webserver setup). In that case you're looking for:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
current_site.domain
```

you'd have to put the current_site object into a template context yourself if you want to use it. If you're using it all over the place, you could package that up in a template context processor.

Comment: To clarify for someone who has the same problems as I had: check that your `SITE_ID` setting is equal to the `id` attribute of the current site in Sites app (you can find the `id` in Sites admin panel). When you call `get_current`, Django takes your `SITE_ID` and returns the `Site` object with that id from the database.

Comment: None of these work for me.
  `print("get_current_site: ", get_current_site(request))
    print("absolute uri: ", request.build_absolute_uri())
    print("HTTP_HOST: ", request.META['HTTP_HOST'])
get_current_site:  localhost:8001
absolute uri: http://localhost:8001/...
HTTP_HOST:  localhost:8001`

Answer (score 133):

I've discovered the [`{{ request.get_host }}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host) method.

Comment: Please note that this answer has the same issues of Daniel Roseman approach (it can be spoofed) but it is surely more complete when the host is reached through an HTTP proxy or load balancer since it takes in account of `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST` HTTP header.

Comment: Usage: "//{{ request.get_host }}/anything/else/you/want"... Be sure to fill in your ALLOWED_HOSTS setting (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts).

Comment: @Seth better to use `request.build_absolute_uri` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri)

Comment: i need to construct the host name for my application dynamically for that i didn't have to use a tenary statement to switch between strings for local development version and production that both needed to test a payment gateway integration system.. using request.get_host() in the view and adding add forward slashed to the returned string did the work

Answer (score 70):

Complementing Carl Meyer, you can make a context processor like this:

#### module.context_processors.py

```
from django.conf import settings

def site(request):
    return {'SITE_URL': settings.SITE_URL}
```

#### local settings.py

```
SITE_URL = 'http://google.com' # this will reduce the Sites framework db call.
```

#### settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    "module.context_processors.site",
    ....
 )
```

#### templates returning context instance the url site is {{ SITE_URL }}

you can write your own rutine if want to handle subdomains or SSL in the context processor.

Comment: I tried this solution but if you have several subdomains for the same application it is not practical, i found very useful the answer by danbruegge

Comment: in settings.py you must introduce your context processor in context_processors>OPTIONS>TEMPLATES

Answer (score 34):

I know this question is old, but I stumbled upon it looking for a pythonic way to get current domain.

```
def myview(request):
    domain = request.build_absolute_uri('/')[:-1]
    # that will build the complete domain: http://foobar.com
```

Comment: `build_absolute_uri` is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri).

Answer (score 33):

Quick and simple, but not good for production:

(in a view)

```
    request.scheme               # http or https
    request.META['HTTP_HOST']    # example.com
    request.path                 # /some/content/1/
```

(in a template)

```
{{ request.scheme }} :// {{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }} {{ request.path }}
```

Be sure to use a [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext), which is the case if you're using [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#render).

Don't trust `request.META['HTTP_HOST']` in production: that info comes from the browser.  Instead, use @CarlMeyer's answer

Comment: I am upvoting this answer but I received an error when trying to use `request.scheme`. Perhaps only available in newer versions of django.

Comment: @MattCremeens `request.scheme` was added in Django 1.7.

Comment: Not being good enough for production is too big of a caveat.

Answer (score 29):

`{{ request.get_host }}` should protect against HTTP Host header attacks when used together with the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting (added in Django 1.4.4).

Note that `{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}` does not have the same protection. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts):

> ALLOWED_HOSTS
>
> A list of strings representing the host/domain names that this Django site can serve. This is a security measure to prevent [HTTP Host header attacks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#host-headers-virtual-hosting), which are possible even under many seemingly-safe web server configurations.
>
> ... If the `Host` header (or `X-Forwarded-Host` if `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST` is enabled) does not match any value in this list, the `django.http.HttpRequest.get_host()` method will raise `SuspiciousOperation`.
>
> ... This validation only applies via `get_host()`; if your code accesses the Host header directly from `request.META` you are bypassing this security protection.

---

As for using the `request` in your template, the template-rendering function calls have [changed in Django 1.8](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.8.x/ref/templates/upgrading.html#django-template-loader), so you no longer have to handle `RequestContext` directly.

Here's how to render a template for a view, using the shortcut function `render()`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

Here's how to render a template for an email, which IMO is the more common case where you'd want the host value:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def my_view(request):
    ...
    email_body = render_to_string(
        'my_template.txt', context, request=request)
```

Here's an example of adding a full URL in an email template; [request.scheme](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.scheme) should get `http` or `https` depending on what you're using:

```
Thanks for registering! Here's your activation link:
{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}{% url 'registration_activate' activation_key %}
```

Comment: The link to Django 1.8 is dead...
Would [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-request) be the equivalent now?

Comment: @JamesBellaby Ah, looks like the page I linked to only exists in older docs versions now. I'll update the link to [this](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.8.x/ref/templates/upgrading.html#django-template-loader). I guess this historical info isn't relevant to most readers today, but it does kind of clarify things against the other old answers here, so I'll keep it.

Comment: This was useful for me for an email template. With the condition `{% if request.get_host == "127.0.0.1:8000" %}` I could display **production** or **development** URL. Dunno if it's a regular way but it works well.

Answer (score 26):

The variation of the context processor I use is:

```
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject


def site(request):
    return {
        'site': SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_current_site(request)),
    }
```

The `SimpleLazyObject` wrapper makes sure the DB call only happens when the template actually uses the `site` object. This removes the query from the admin pages. It also caches the result.

and include it in the settings:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    "module.context_processors.site",
    ....
)
```

In the template, you can use `{{ site.domain }}` to get the current domain name.

**edit:** to support protocol switching too, use:

```
def site(request):
    site = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_current_site(request))
    protocol = 'https' if request.is_secure() else 'http'

    return {
        'site': site,
        'site_root': SimpleLazyObject(lambda: "{0}://{1}".format(protocol, site.domain)),
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to use `SimpleLazyObject` here, because the lambda wont be called if nothing accesses 'site' anyway.

Comment: If you remove the `SimpleLazyObject`, each `RequestContext` will call `get_current_site()`, and therefore execute an SQL query. The wrapper makes sure the variable is only evaluated when it's actually used in the template.

Comment: Since it's a function, the host string won't be processed unless it's used anyway. So, you can just assign a function to 'site_root' and you don't need SimpleLazyObject.

Django will call the function when it's used. You've already created the necessary function with a lambda here anyway.

Comment: Ah yes, only a lambda would work. The `SimpleLazyObject` is there to avoid reevaluation of the function, which isn't really needed since the `Site` object is cached.

Comment: The import is now `from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site`

Answer (score 10):

I use a custom template tag. Add to e.g. `<your_app>/templatetags/site.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django import template
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def current_domain():
    return 'http://%s' % Site.objects.get_current().domain
```

Use it in a template like this:

```
{% load site %}
{% current_domain %}
```

Comment: Is there any particular downside to this approach? Apart from the call to the Site db on every request.

Comment: @kicker86 I don't know any. `get_current` is a documented method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#hooking-into-the-current-site-from-views

Comment: `'http://%s'` could be a problem in case of `https` connection; scheme is not dynamic in this case.

Answer (score 9):

If you use the ["request" context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-request), and are using the [Django sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/sites/), and have the [Site middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/sites/#site-middleware) installed (i.e. your settings include these):

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "django.contrib.sites",
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
     "django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware",
    ...
]
```

... then you will have the `request` object available in templates, and it will contain a reference to the current `Site` for the request as `request.site`.  You can then retrieve the domain in a template with:

```
    {{request.site.domain}}
```

and the site name with:

```
    {{request.site.name}}
```

Answer (score 6):

Similar to user panchicore's reply, this is what I did on a very simple website.
It provides a few variables and makes them available on the template.

`SITE_URL` would hold a value like `example.com`
`SITE_PROTOCOL` would hold a value like `http`  or `https`
`SITE_PROTOCOL_URL` would hold a value like `http://example.com` or `https://example.com`
`SITE_PROTOCOL_RELATIVE_URL` would hold a value like `//example.com`.

**module/context_processors.py**

```
from django.conf import settings

def site(request):

    SITE_PROTOCOL_RELATIVE_URL = '//' + settings.SITE_URL

    SITE_PROTOCOL = 'http'
    if request.is_secure():
        SITE_PROTOCOL = 'https'

    SITE_PROTOCOL_URL = SITE_PROTOCOL + '://' + settings.SITE_URL

    return {
        'SITE_URL': settings.SITE_URL,
        'SITE_PROTOCOL': SITE_PROTOCOL,
        'SITE_PROTOCOL_URL': SITE_PROTOCOL_URL,
        'SITE_PROTOCOL_RELATIVE_URL': SITE_PROTOCOL_RELATIVE_URL
    }
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    "module.context_processors.site",
    ....
 )

SITE_URL = 'example.com'
```

Then, on your templates, use them as `{{ SITE_URL }}`, `{{ SITE_PROTOCOL }}`, `{{ SITE_PROTOCOL_URL }}` and `{{ SITE_PROTOCOL_RELATIVE_URL }}`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`request.build_absolute_uri()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri)

By default, it will return a full path.

But if you pass in a parameter like this:

```
request.build_absolute_uri('/')
```

This would return the domain name.

Answer (score 4):

In a Django template you can do:

```
<a href="{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}{{ request.path }}?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}" >link</a>
```

Comment: This worked for me thank you.
I had to enable request in TEMPLATES, context_processors: `django.template.context_processors.request`, also [this how-to helped](
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/07/20/django-tip-7-how-to-get-the-current-url-within-a-django-template.html)

Comment: Agree, Vitor Freitas blog is a great source for Django developers! :)

Answer (score 1):

What about this approach? Works for me.
It is also used in [django-registration](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration/blob/8c0acebbec298ce8971650b93abcbc07d0326354/registration/backends/hmac/views.py#L74).

```
def get_request_root_url(self):
    scheme = 'https' if self.request.is_secure() else 'http'
    site = get_current_site(self.request)
    return '%s://%s' % (scheme, site)
```

Comment: But trying it with `localhost` will get you an `https` scheme (It's considered secure) which won't work if you've got static url (only `http://127.0.0.1` is valid, not `https://127.0.0.1`). So it's not ideal when still in development.

Answer (score 1):

I figure what we want is an alternative to the existing `url` tag, so I wrote a new tag:

```
from django.template import Library
from django.urls     import reverse

@register.simple_tag(takes_context = True)
def fullURL(context, name, *args, **kwargs):
    request = context['request']
    return f'{request.scheme}://{request.get_host()}{reverse(name, args = args, kwargs = kwargs)}'
```

Then in your template you can have this...

```
{% extends "myapp/email/email_base.html" %}

{% load mytags %} {# Replace mytags with whatever the name of your custom tags calss is. #}

{% block content %}
<p>You can use <a href="{% fullURL 'signup' %}">this link</a> to get started with your account. We look forward to seeing you soon!</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Then when you generate this, you just need to remember to pass the `request` into the `context`, like so...

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def sendEmail(subject, to, template, **context):
    html = render_to_string(f'myapp/email/{template}.html', context | {'subject': subject})
    # ... and so on with the rest of my function for sending email...
```

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to in @furins response there may be issues with proxy servers. I found this myself when using Apache and uWSGI – `request.get_host` or `request.build_absolute_uri` would return the proxy host (127.0.0.1:9191…).

However, someone has helpfully posted a guide to fixing this:

https://ubuntu.com/blog/django-behind-a-proxy-fixing-absolute-urls

Although this is a relatively old answer, it is still relevant to django 3.2 and python 3.9.

Just in case the answer disappears in the future, here is the gist of it:

settings.py

```
# Setup support for proxy headers
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

apache.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto 'https' env=HTTPS

    ProxyPass / http://10.0.0.3/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.0.3/
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

With these settings `request.get_host` and `request.build_absolute_uri` reference the client requested host and not the proxy host.

Answer (score 1):

These below can get **a full url** and **parts of url**:

```py
def myview(request):
    request.build_absolute_uri()
    # http://localhost:8000/admin/store/product/

    request.build_absolute_uri('/')
    # http://localhost:8000/

    request.build_absolute_uri('/')[:-1]
    # http://localhost:8000

    request.scheme
    # http

    request.META['HTTP_HOST']
    # localhost:8000

    request.path    
    # /admin/store/product/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
if Site._meta.installed:
    site = Site.objects.get_current()
else:
    site = RequestSite(request)
```

Answer (score -7):

You can use `{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}` in your templates to get your domain name.

Comment: I don't think that @Erwan notices that this depends on a non-standard request context processor.

Comment: I could not make this work, where do you define protocol and domain?

Comment: domain has to be added to the context by the developer.