# accessing project url in django template

Tags: python, django, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I access constants in settings.py from templates in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433162/can-i-access-constants-in-settings-py-from-templates-in-django)

I am trying to create a template , which contains some hyperlinks and  redirect url. I have seperate production and staging server .  I have already tried `request.get_full_path` on template but it is  rendering query string rather than domain name. Any idea?

in settings.py i did following

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
     "django.core.context_processors.request",
     "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth"

     )
```

My template is as follows

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sumit_1349250468_per@ersumit.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="registration charge {{ request.session.username }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="{{ request.session.userid }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="{{ request.get_full_path}}accounts/success">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="{{ request.get_full_path}}/accounts/sorry">

</form>
```

**I don't want to create any custom views**

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433162/can-i-access-constants-in-settings-py-from-templates-in-django

Comment: @Rohan : I dont want to create custom views.. i am using django registration , so i want to use constant from settings.py on registation_complete.html

Comment: Please read up the mentioned question and answers. There are multiple answers with different approaches.

Comment: With or without "custom views", this is never going to work: PROJECT_ROOT is a file path, which has no place in a URL.

Comment: You could follow the link posted by Rohan to make `PROJECT_ROOT` accessible in the template. But be warned that its unsafe to show the variable to public and even rely it in furthering logic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451138/how-can-i-get-the-domain-name-of-my-site-within-a-django-template i found it .. sorry all to waste your time .. should i delete this question?