# How to get the domain name in django view function?

Tags: python, django

My application is going to be hosted in multiple domains, I need a domain name in django view function...How to achieve this? I am using django 1.3.3.

I want something like this

www.syz.com
127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `request.get_host()`

Doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host

Or in your template (if you use a requestContext) `{{request.get_host}}`

as @jayanth-koushik mentionned it, you can find more here: [How can I get the domain name of my site within a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451138/how-can-i-get-the-domain-name-of-my-site-within-a-django-template)