# {{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }} not supported in Djagno 1.6.4? Easy way to get the host URL?

Tags: python, django

I was using {{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }} in Django 1.5 and after upgrading to 1.6 the tag is no longer working.

What is the easiest way to get the the URL/Host directly in the template without writing some custom views etc?

Is there another tag that I can use directly in my template with Django 1.6?

Comment: Multiple solutions, some more robust than others, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451138/how-can-i-get-the-domain-name-of-my-site-within-a-django-template

Answer (score 1):

Use [`request.get_host()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host):

> Returns the originating host of the request using information from the
>   HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST (if USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST is enabled) and
>   HTTP_HOST headers, in that order.

Answer (score 1):

The `get_host()` method fails when the host is behind multiple proxies. One solution is to use middleware to rewrite the proxy headers, as in the following example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host