# How to get getting base_url in django template

Tags: python, django

Given a website, how would you get the HOST of that in a django template, without passing that var from the view?

```
http://google.com/hello --> {{ BASE_URL }} ==> 'http://google.com'
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This has been answered extensively in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451138/how-can-i-get-the-domain-name-of-my-site-within-a-django-template)

There are several ways of doing it:

1. As david542 described **
2. Using `{{ request.get_host }}` in your template **
3. Using the `contrib.sites` framework

** Please note these can be spoofed

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer/options. Could you please add a bit on 'how' the first two can be spoofed?

Comment: The first two depend on the request meta data, which essentially is coming from a browser. This can be fixed with the allowed hosts setting, on which more info can be found here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: Without `()` in django templates, i. e. `{{ request.get_host }}`.

Answer (score 24):

None of these other answers take scheme into account. This is what worked for me:

```
{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}
```

Answer (score 4):

**URL: `google.com/hello`**

**In Template:**

```
{{ request.get_full_path() }}
return /hello

OR

{{ request.get_host() }}
return google.com
```

**In view:**

```
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site

def home(request):
    get_current_site(request)
    # google.com

    # OR
    request.get_host()
    # google.com

    # OR
    request.get_full_path()
    # /hello
```

Comment: Without `()` in django templates, i. e. `{{ request.get_host }}` for the base url.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `request` object in your template by adding in the following `TEMPLECT_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR` middleware in your settings:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

Here is some [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) on it. Then you can call in your template:

```
{{ request.META.HTTP_NAME }}
```

And that will give you the base url.

Answer (score 1):

In your template to get base url

```
{{ request.get_host() }}
```