# Django sending emails with links

Tags: python, django, url

I have a sending code:

```
def send_email(site_id, email):
    subject = "Sub"
    from_email, to = EMAIL_FROM, email
    text_content = 'Text'
    html_content = render_to_string(
        'app/includes/email.html',
        {'pk': site_id}
    )
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

And in my template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="{% url 'mail_view' pk %}">Click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

But this code generate link like this:
http://mail.google.com/en-us/results/30/

results/30 it's fine,
but I get mail.google.com instead "mysite.com"
and in my site there is no /en-us/ its only /en/

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: what does that `mail_view` do? Is that your view or from any other third party's?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are missing the absolute url in the link within your email template.  When you send out an email, django fills in the url with a relative url "/results/30/" and perhaps your gmail mail client is filling in url with it's own domain and language prefix path.

You might try something like this:

```
<a href="https://yoursite.com{% url 'mail_view' pk %}">Click</a>
```

Or to avoid hard-coding your domain in your template, you can use one of the techniques suggested below using the django sites framework or similar:

[How can I get the domain name of my site within a Django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451138/how-can-i-get-the-domain-name-of-my-site-within-a-django-template)