# How to send links through email in django?

Tags: python, django, email

I am learning how to send emails in django. Now, i want to try to send links as a message in email.
please help me how to do it. It would be a great help.

this is my views.py

```
def send(request):
    send_mail(
        "Subject",
        "This is a test sample mail https://www.google.com/ ",
        'sample.mail.2101@gmail.com',
        ['padow76087@chclzq.com'],
        fail_silently=False)
    return redirect('/')
```

thanku for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your email template to render a html file and include the url in the html file. For more refer this link [Django sending emails with links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054658/django-sending-emails-with-links)

Comment: i am unable to understand whatever code is written there as i am just a beginner