# Displaying my current domain in my django template not working

Tags: python, django

I send a html email to the users using the `EmailMultiAlternatives` and it worked, but the problem is in the email message the link is not working.

But when I tried doing `<a href="http://127.0.0.1{% url 'add_your_details' user.username %}">` then it worked perfectly as I wanted.

template

```
<a href="{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}{% url 'add_your_details' user.username %}" 
target="_blank">Add your details </a>
```

settings

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']
```

Comment: Please Checkout this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451138/how-can-i-get-the-domain-name-of-my-site-within-a-django-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the    **[get_current_site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sites/#get-current-site-shortcut)**   method.

In views:

```
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site

my_current_domain = get_current_site(request)
return {'domain':my_current_domain}
```

then in template

```
<a href="{{ request.scheme }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'add_your_details' user.username %}" 
target="_blank">Add your details </a>
```